# Map data from an array for only some keys (not filtered)

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, mapping

I have a d3 pie chart. It reads data from a json file (in this example it's just an array variable).

Some of the key names are not very helpful, so I am trying to write a map function to pass some different strings, but other key names are fine, so I want to skip over those or return them as normal.

If a key name is not declared my function returns undefined. Also the names are not being added to the legend.

I do know all of the key names, but I would rather continue over the ones I have not defined as they can be returned as they are, if this is possible (I thought an `else/if` with a `continue` condition). This code would be more useful if new keys are added to the data.

I have tested a version with all key names declared, it stops throwing an undefined variable, but is not appending the new key names to the legend.

There is a full jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/lharby/ugweordj/6/

Here is my js function (truncated).

```
 var w = 400,
    h = 400,
    r = 180,
    inner = 70,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

data = [{"label":"OOS", "value":194}, 
        {"label":"TH10", "value":567}, 
        {"label":"OK", "value":1314},
        {"label":"KO", "value":793},
        {"label":"Spark", "value":1929}];

mapData = data.map(function(d){
    if(d.label == 'OOS'){
        return 'Out of scope';
    }else if(d.label == 'TH10'){
        return 'Threshold 10';
    }else{
       // I don't care about the other keys, they can map as they are. 
        continue;
    }
});

var total = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
    return d3.sum(d3.values(d));
});

var vis = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .data([data])
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + r * 1.1 + "," + r * 1.1 + ")")

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(inner)
    .outerRadius(r);

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) { return d.value; });

var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
    .data(pie)
    .enter()
    ///
    };

arcs.append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } )
    .attr("d", arc);

var legend = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("width", r)
    .attr("height", r * 2)
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(mapData) // returning mapData up until undefined variables
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); });

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.label; }); // should this point to a reference in mapData?
```

The HTML is a simple element with an id of `#chart`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.forEach()` to iterate over your data and change just the labels of interest while keeping all others unchanged:

```js
data = [{"label":"OOS", "value":194}, 
        {"label":"TH10", "value":567}, 
        {"label":"OK", "value":1314},
        {"label":"KO", "value":793},
        {"label":"Spark", "value":1929}];

data.forEach(d => {
  if(d.label == 'OOS'){
    d.label = 'Out of scope';
  } else if(d.label == 'TH10'){
    d.label = 'Threshold 10';
  }
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Excellent, this seems a better route. As I can still pass the original data object to the various d3 functions. Thank you.

Comment: Sometimes it's hard to choose.

Answer (score 2):

You **cannot** skip elements using `map`. However, you can skip them using `reduce`:

```js
var data = [
    {"label":"OOS", "value":194}, 
    {"label":"TH10", "value":567}, 
    {"label":"OK", "value":1314},
    {"label":"KO", "value":793},
    {"label":"Spark", "value":1929}
];

var mapData = data.reduce(function(result, d) {
    if (d.label == 'OOS') {
        result.push('Out of scope');
    } else if (d.label == 'TH10') {
        result.push('Threshold 10');
    };
    return result;
}, []);

console.log(mapData)
```

EDIT: after your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390915/map-data-from-an-array-for-only-some-keys-not-filtered/47391107?noredirect=1#comment81735254_47391107) your desired outcome is clearer. You ca do this using `map`, just return the property's value:

```js
var data = [{"label":"OOS", "value":194}, 
        {"label":"TH10", "value":567}, 
        {"label":"OK", "value":1314},
        {"label":"KO", "value":793},
        {"label":"Spark", "value":1929}];

var mapData = data.map(function(d) {
  if (d.label == 'OOS') {
    return 'Out of scope';
  } else if (d.label == 'TH10') {
    return 'Threshold 10';
  } else {
    return d.label
  }
});

console.log(mapData);
```

Comment: OK thank you. Maybe skip is the wrong word. I don't want to reduce the set. I still want to push `'KO'` and `'OK'` but  `'OOS'` should read `'Out of scope'`, if that makes sense.